# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function chdir()

Tags: bootstrapping

I tried to copy my site to a new sever and since id did that, I get an *HTTP-Fehler 500 (Internal Server Error):* on certain pages. The log files are reporting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function chdir() in /var/customers/webs/something/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3384
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function max() in /var/customers/webs/something/includes/lock.inc on line 106
```

I cleared all caches many times with:

```
drush cc all
```

and also flushed the cache tables directly with MySQL commands. I disabled APC. I don't think, that this is a problem with the server, because it serves well for other Durpal sites.

EDIT: Here are my [php.ini](http://pastebin.com/crjUDY8q) and [htaccess](http://pastebin.com/MmzCPPLi).

Comment: Is the new server or vhost in PHP safe mode?  What does status report say?

Comment: What's your php version, by the way? Even in safe mode chdir is defined, so @MPD suggestion does not explain it all - but is a good starting point. And max is plainly safe.

Comment: @MPD The server is a vhost and PHP is in safe mode. But the status report does not complain for safe mode restrictions and I get no Drupal error messages either.

Answer (score 2):

`chdir()` and `max()` are built in functions that always exists in PHP. They are in no plugin, just a core. Even in safe mode both should be defined.

There is one way to disable them and make them non-existent from the script's point of view. `disable_functions` section in php.ini does the trick. Usually it is used for safety, like this:

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

and whilst I can see some illusionary* safety in disabling `chdir()`, disabling `max()` must have been a mistake. Note that on some configurations you can alter ini settings in `.htaccess` and via `ini_set()` too.

*Illusionary due to the same reasons that made [Safe Mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for clarify that, but the functions mentioned above are not disabled in php.ini or elsewhere.

Comment: @user5950 So what's your PHP version? Anyway if there **is** safe mode at all, you are using pretty old PHP version. Could you post your `php.ini` and `.htaccess`?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.24-1. I posted the files above.

Comment: @user5950 nothing that could block these functions there. Weird. Can you output `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: Finally I found the cause of that problem: I get those or similar messages when the server runs out of memory.